# Thunderbird TbSync plugin not compatible... but compatible?

Tags: thunderbird, plugin

OS: Ubuntu/Linux 20.04
Thunderbird: 102.2.2

My calendar stopped working, and it appears that the reason for that is that the TbSync plugin is not compatible with TB 102.2.2. No updates of the plugin are available. However, when I click on "more information" I get a message saying "The add-on “TbSync” seems to be maintained and is compatible with Thunderbird 102.".

What do I do? I must have a working calendar in my e-mail app. So far I tried to reinstall everything, which took quite some time, but this did not help.

I considered going back to an earlier version of TB, 102.1 maybe, but `apt policy thunderbird` does not list any versions between the ancient 68.7 and 102.2.2.

Comment: Is this for Outlook/Office365? Or some other provider? If it's for Outlook/Office365 you need to migrate away from Basic Authentication to OAuth. If you've not done that yet you should delete your calendar and re-add it. (Or do what I did, which is to add a new one and then delete the old.)

Comment: This does not explain why the add-ons stopped working.

Comment: Unless you define "_stopped working_" it could easily explain why your calendar no longer displays appointments.

Comment: Precisely, that is what I wrote in my original question ("TbSync plugin is not compatible"). Note that I did not ask about calendar but about the compatibility of the TbSync plugin. The question of authentication does not arise if the plugin is not enabled at all – since it is not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution - sort of. I have added the mozilla ppa to my Ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

When thunderbird was updated to version 102.4.1, the extensions - and my calendar – were working again.